# TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date

Tags: python, datetime, data-science

I am going to filter the dataset with datetime, suddenly the issue happened.

**These are libraries that I used**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**Coding**

```
df_6m = df_uk[(df_uk.InvoiceDate < date(2011,9,1)) & (df_uk.InvoiceDate >= date(2011,3,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
df_next = df_uk[(df_uk.InvoiceDate >= date(2011,9,1)) & (df_uk.InvoiceDate < date(2011,12,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try

```
df_6m = df_uk[(df_uk.InvoiceDate < pd.to_datetime("2011-9-1")) & (df_uk.InvoiceDate >= pd.to_datetime("2011-3-1"))].reset_index(drop=True)
df_next = df_uk[(df_uk.InvoiceDate >= pd.to_datetime("2011-9-1")) & (df_uk.InvoiceDate < pd.to_datetime("2011-12-1"))].reset_index(drop=True)
```